# MySQL to Find the first occurrence where the time difference is bigger than 5 minutes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id | created
1  | 1563220108
2  | 1563220408
3  | 1563220608
4  | 1563220808
5  | 1563220908
```

I want to find the lowest ID, where the difference between the current row and the other row is more than 5 minutes.

If you look at my sample data, the difs are as follows:

```
id | created     | dif
1  | 1563220108  | null
2  | 1563220408  | 300
3  | 1563220608  | 500
4  | 1563220808  | 700
5  | 1563220908  | 800
```

5 x 60 = 300. So, in this case, I would like 2 to be returned.

If id = 2, was instead 301 seconds apart, then it would need to return id = 3.

I am struggling to get my brain to figure out how to write a query that looks at row 1, then row X + 1, then row X + 2 etc. It's not directly comparing the NEXT row. It must compare the first row with the next row, then the first row with the 3rd row, then first row with the 4th row and so forth. Is this even possible with mysql?

**UPDATE**

Version: 10.1.36-MariaDB

**UPDATE 2**

I have a database that stores points every couple of seconds. I am trying to write a script that deletes any points that are less than 5 minutes apart. The goal is to decrease the total size of the database, because I don't need to store so many points. I only need points once every 15 minutes or so.

So to do this, I need a script that can find the first id in the table, where the difference between this id and another following row, is bigger than 5 minutes. SO I take it back. It needs to not compare X + 2 and X + 3. It must ALWAYS just compare it with the next value!

So I need a table like this:

```
id | created     | dif
1  | 1563220108  | null
2  | 1563220408  | 300
3  | 1563220608  | 200
4  | 1563220808  | 200
5  | 1563220908  | 100
```

From this, I should be able to do what I need to do. Going to fiddle and see if I can get this myself.

Comment: Which MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @coderama . . . Your question is unclear.  Before the updates, you want one row returned -- quite explicitly ("5 x 60 = 300. So, in this case, I would like 2 to be returned").  Then you say you want more rows in the second update.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is named `time_data`

```
SELECT AA.id, MIN(BB.id)
FROM time_data AA
  INNER JOIN time_data BB
    ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, AA.created, BB.created) > 5
GROUP BY AA.id
```

Comment: Based on update looks like OP want remove extra record to keep difference between records less than 5 minutes.

Comment: OP said "where the difference between the current row and the other row is more than 5 minutes."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery and ordering:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.created < t.created and
                        t2.created >= t.created - 5 * 60
                 )
order by t.id asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Based on update looks like OP want remove extra record to keep difference between records less than 5 minutes.

Comment: correlated subquery should be avoided because they can be slow.

Comment: @MarlinPierce . . . That is simply untrue as a general statement.

Comment: (Incidentally, 5 * 60 = 300)

Comment: @GordonLinoff https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery  Whenever you have a correlated subquery, for every row considered by the main query, the database has to do a whole query.  (It is not slow with the subquery is not correlated.)

Comment: @MarlinPierce . . . That is a *logical* explanation of what the processing does.  SQL is a *declarative* language.  The optimizer is free to choose any method of executing the query, so long as the results are the same.  Further, even that description does not take indexes into account.